# How to convert molar volume to volume?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, concentration, ideal-gas, equation-of-state

This seems like a simple question that people must have asked already, but I can't find an answer online.

I'm not a chemist, but need to use a code that deals with thermodynamics.  I am trying to use an input data file from an older code but have to convert it to the form the current code uses.  I'm having problems understanding how to deal with the volume term.

In the previous code, there's molar volume in cm3 mol-1.  In the current code, I need to input volume in J bar-1.  I know I can do a simple units conversion by multiplying the molar volume value by 0.1.  However, I have an uncomfortable feeling that there's something I'm not understanding.

Do I need to worry about an equation of state to do things properly?  I'll be dealing with solids (not liquid or gas) at a room pressure and temperature but don't want to make any simplifying assumptions.  Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 4):

If you have given

- the molar volume $V_\text{m}$ in $\pu{cm3 mol-1}$,
- the molar amount in $\pu{mol}$,

you get the volume as $V = n \cdot V_\text{m}\ [\pu{cm3}] = 0.1 \cdot  n \cdot V_\text{m}\ [\pu{J bar-1}]$.

As $$\pu{J bar-1} = \dfrac{\pu{N m} }{ \pu{e5 Pa}} = \dfrac{\pu{N m3}}{ \pu{e5 N}} = \pu{e-5 m3} = \pu{10 cm3} = \pu{10 mL}$$

Note that this is the first time I have even seen to express volume in such a unit.

Comment: I had to do a similar thing while deriving the formula for molar conductivity from conductivity. My rep was too low to comment and thus I could not answer before @Poutnik